# "lea eax, [a]" is not the same as "mov eax, a"

Tags: assembly, x86

My understanding of lea is it loads address rather than value, and "lea eax, [a]" is the same as "mov eax, a".
However, when I write code "mov eax, printf", the address of printf function is not loaded into eax and calling the address result in seg fault.
If I change it to "lea eax, [printf]", then correct address is loaded and calling works as intended.
I am assembly beginner. Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: That should work. Post [mcve] and specify OS.

Comment: Which assembler are you using?  Is it MASM?  In that case you need `mov eax, OFFSET printf`.  Also, you left out the comma.  Does that actually assemble?

Comment: I am using MASM and and adding OFFSET works. Thanks! Why is OFFSET needed in this case?

Comment: @user607722: Because `mov eax, printf` is a 4-byte load from that address, same as always for MASM.

Comment: `mov eax,printf` in MASM is like `mov eax,[printf]` ... what do you mean "why?", the syntax of assembler is defined by authors of assembler, ask MS...